# Sorting socks after laundry.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Yesterday sorting socks after laundry I came across the following problem. Assume we have a bin with $n$ pairs of objects. We draw an object from the bin. If there is a paired object on the table we put both objects in another bin. Otherwise we lay the unpaired object on the table.

What is the probability that after $k$ draws the second bin contains $m$ pairs of objects?

I took the following approach. Assume we already have $m-1$ pairs in the second bin after $k-1$ draws. This means we have $k-1-2(m-1)=k-2m+1$ unpaired objects on the table. Similarly one can treat the case if there are already $m$ pairs in the second bin before the $k$-th draw.
The considerations boil down to the following recurrence relation for the probability in question:
$$
P_n(k,m)=P_n(k-1,m-1)\frac{k-2m+1}{2n-k+1}+P_n(k-1,m)\frac{2(n+m-k+1)}{2n-k+1};\quad 
P_n(0,m)=\delta_{0m}.\tag1
$$

The calculations based on the expression (1) show reasonable values (here for $n=7$):

$$%\left(
\begin{array}{r|cccccccc}
&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\hline
0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2& \frac{12}{13} & \frac{1}{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3& \frac{10}{13} & \frac{3}{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4& \frac{80}{143} & \frac{60}{143} & \frac{3}{143} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5& \frac{48}{143} & \frac{80}{143} & \frac{15}{143} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
6& \frac{64}{429} & \frac{80}{143} & \frac{40}{143} & \frac{5}{429} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
7& \frac{16}{429} & \frac{56}{143} & \frac{70}{143} & \frac{35}{429} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
8& 0 & \frac{64}{429} & \frac{80}{143} & \frac{40}{143} & \frac{5}{429} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
9& 0 & 0 & \frac{48}{143} & \frac{80}{143} & \frac{15}{143} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
10& 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{80}{143} & \frac{60}{143} & \frac{3}{143} & 0 & 0 \\
11& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{10}{13} & \frac{3}{13} & 0 & 0 \\
12& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{12}{13} & \frac{1}{13} & 0 \\
13& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
14& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
%\right)
$$

Moreover the values look so nice and symmetric $$P_n(k,m)=P_n(2n-k,m+n-k)$$ that I would assume the existence of a closed form expression for the probability. However I could not find it. Is there possibly a way to avoid the recursion altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{2n}k$ ways to choose $k$ socks and $\binom nm$ ways to choose $m$ pairs.  Now we have $n-m$ unchosen pairs remaining, and we have to draw an unmatched sock from $k-2m$ of them.  The pairs can be chosen in in $\binom{n-m}{k-2m}$ ways, and for each pair, we have a choice of two socks.

This gives $$\frac{\binom nm\binom{n-m}{k-2m}2^{k-2m}}{\binom {2n}k}$$ for the probability.  I confirmed that for $n=7$ this gives the values shown in the table in the question.